The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2F59B5F99B1BE0B4 in linux
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 system and When I try to run
sudo apt update

The below error occurs:
vijay@vijay-ThinkPad-E15-Gen-2:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  InRelease [1,572 B]
Get:3 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-9.0.0  InRelease [1,572 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-12-4-local  InRelease [1,572 B]
Get:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local  Release [564 B]
Get:3 file:/var/cudnn-local-repo-ubuntu2204-9.0.0  InRelease [1,572 B]
Get:4 file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local  Release [564 B]
Hit:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro InRelease                                                                                                                                              
Hit:7 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                           
Err:6 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro InRelease                                                                                                                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2F59B5F99B1BE0B4
Hit:8 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                  
Hit:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease                                                                                               
Hit:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                                               
Hit:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease               
Hit:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Hit:13 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: file:/var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-2-local/Release.gpg: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x nodistro InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2F59B5F99B1BE0B4
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x/dists/nodistro/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2F59B5F99B1BE0B4
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.


I have checked to fix this I got solutions like the below command:
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2F59B5F99B1BE0B4

The execution ecnds as below:
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.5riFaj3RU8/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2F59B5F99B1BE0B4
gpg: key 2F59B5F99B1BE0B4: "NSolid <nsolid-gpg@nodesource.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1


But this is not solved the issue. When I run again
 sudo apt update 

It throws the same error.
I don't know how to fix this. How to debug the exact problem.

I looked up more about this issue and found this article that I think might solve your second issue (apt-key) to ultimately fix your first issue (signature verification issue)
I will resume the post's content below, although I encourage you to read the post since it explains why apt-key is deprecated and the huge security risks it brings.
Here are the steps:

Download the key:
wget https://host.domain.tld/path/to/<keyfile>.<ext>

(No need for -O or >; wget defaults to saving the file in your current directory with the same filename it has on the server.)

Verify that the filetype is "PGP public key block Public-Key (old)":
-file <keyfile>.<ext>

gpg supports a number of key formats, so if your key is in a different format, convert it by importing it into a temp keyring, then exporting it again:

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./temp-keyring.gpg --import <keyfile>.<ext>

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring ./temp-keyring.gpg --export --output <your-keyfile-name>.gpg

rm temp-keyring.gpg




Now that you have your converted key, do not add it to apt's trusted keystore by copying it into /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/. Instead, put it somewhere like /etc/apt/keyrings/. (You might need to create that keyrings directory first.) There's nothing special about that location, it's just a convention recommended by man 5 sources.list in Ubuntu 22.04 and a related Debian Wiki entry.
At this point, nothing has changed and apt doesn't know the key exists. The last step is to modify the specific .list file for the repository to tell apt where to find the key for that specific repo.
Edit the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<example>.list, and in between deb and the url, add [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/<your-keyfile-name>.gpg]
Now apt will accept that key's signature for all packages in that repo and only that repo.
Notes:

If you already have keyring files in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/, you can move them to /etc/apt/keyrings/ as-is, and then update all the corresponding .list files so each one has a signed-by field pointing to its own key.

If you already have keys in the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg keyring file beyond the official repo keys, this answer details the steps to locate and remove them. You can then follow all the same steps above to set them up the safer way. (Exporting them from that keyring is also possible, but the exact steps are left as an exercise for the reader.)

To import a repo's key from a keyserver to a standalone file:

gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring <output-file-name>.gpg --keyserver <some.keyserver.uri> --recv-keys <fingerprint>

This should give you a key that apt will accept without conversion.



Apt is still very trusting, and a malicious or compromised repo can bypass this measure easily because packages currently can run arbitrary shell code as root in their setup scripts. Closing off one attack vector doesn't hurt, though, and progress is (slowly) being made on other fronts.

Optionally, you can switch to the newer, more verbose Deb822 format using individual .sources files instead of .list files. It's more work, but personally I find the result far more readable.


Sources:

Debian Wiki
Excellent and detailed answer on Unix&Linux StackExchange

Again, this answer is from this article, I hope it fixes your issue.
